# Trying to get .htaccess to skip one directory - not working

Tags: .htaccess

I know this question has been asked a million times but I've been searching and trying various things for a day and half and I'm not having any luck.  Any help would sure be appreciated.

I have a CMS (in this case the Dolphin social networking script) but I need to introduce some other code.  I'm trying to get this .htaccess file to not redirect on the directory 'bricks'.  I'm not having any luck at all.

Here is the .htaccess as it exists now:

```
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
suPHP_ConfigPath /home/columbu5
<Files php.ini>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
</IfModule>

Options -MultiViews -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^bricks/(.*)$  bricks/ [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^blogs/{0,1}$   modules/boonex/blogs/blogs.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^blogs/all/{0,1}$  modules/boonex/blogs/blogs.php?action=all  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^blogs/all/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/{0,1}$  modules/boonex/blogs/blogs.php?page=$2&per_page=$1  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^blogs/top/{0,1}$   modules/boonex/blogs/blogs.php?action=top_blogs [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^blogs/top/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/{0,1}$   modules/boonex/blogs/blogs.php?action=top_blogs&page=$2&per_page=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^blogs/top_posts/{0,1}$   modules/boonex/blogs/blogs.php?action=top_posts [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^blogs/top_posts/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/{0,1}$   modules/boonex/blogs/blogs.php?action=top_posts&page=$2&per_page=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^blogs/tag/([^/.]+)/{0,1}$   modules/boonex/blogs/blogs.php?action=search_by_tag&tagKey=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^blogs/tag/{0,1}$   modules/boonex/blogs/blogs.php?action=search_by_tag&tagKey= [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^blogs/posts/([^/.]+)/tag/([^/.]+)/{0,1}$   modules/boonex/blogs/blogs.php?action=search_by_tag&tagKey=$2&ownerName=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^blogs/posts/([^/.]+)/category/([^/.]+)/{0,1}$   modules/boonex/blogs/blogs.php?action=show_member_blog&ownerName=$1&categoryUri=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^blogs/entry/([^/.]+)/{0,1}$   modules/boonex/blogs/blogs.php?action=show_member_post&postUri=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^blogs/entry/{0,1}$    modules/boonex/blogs/blogs.php?action=show_member_post&postUri= [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^blogs/posts/([^/.]+)/{0,1}$   modules/boonex/blogs/blogs.php?action=show_member_blog&ownerName=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^blogs/posts/{0,1}$   modules/boonex/blogs/blogs.php?action=show_member_blog&ownerName= [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^blogs/posts/([^/.]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/{0,1}$   modules/boonex/blogs/blogs.php?action=show_member_blog&ownerName=$1&page=$3&per_page=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^blogs/posts/([^/.]+)/category/([^/.]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/{0,1}$   modules/boonex/blogs/blogs.php?action=show_member_blog&ownerName=$1&categoryUri=$2&page=$4&per_page=$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^blogs/home/{0,1}$   modules/boonex/blogs/blogs.php?action=home [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^blogs/all_posts/{0,1}$   modules/boonex/blogs/blogs.php?action=all_posts [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^blogs/popular_posts/{0,1}$   modules/boonex/blogs/blogs.php?action=popular_posts [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^blogs/featured_posts/{0,1}$   modules/boonex/blogs/blogs.php?action=featured_posts [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^blogs/tags/{0,1}$   modules/boonex/blogs/blogs.php?action=tags [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^blogs/show_calendar/{0,1}$   modules/boonex/blogs/blogs.php?action=show_calendar [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^blogs/my_page/{0,1}$   modules/boonex/blogs/blogs.php?action=my_page&mode=main [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^blogs/my_page/add/{0,1}$   modules/boonex/blogs/blogs.php?action=my_page&mode=add [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^blogs/my_page/manage/{0,1}$   modules/boonex/blogs/blogs.php?action=my_page&mode=manage [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^blogs/my_page/pending/{0,1}$   modules/boonex/blogs/blogs.php?action=my_page&mode=pending [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^blogs/my_page/edit/([0-9]+)/{0,1}$  modules/boonex/blogs/blogs.php?action=edit_post&EditPostID=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^blogs/member_posts/([0-9]+)/{0,1}$   modules/boonex/blogs/blogs.php?action=show_member_blog&ownerID=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^blogs/category/([^/.]+)/{0,1}$   modules/boonex/blogs/blogs.php?action=category&uri=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^ads/{0,1}$  modules/boonex/ads/classifieds.php?Browse=1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^ads/my_page/{0,1}$  modules/boonex/ads/classifieds.php?action=my_page [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^ads/my_page/add/{0,1}$  modules/boonex/ads/classifieds.php?action=my_page&mode=add [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^ads/my_page/edit/([0-9]+)/{0,1}$  modules/boonex/ads/classifieds.php?action=my_page&mode=add&EditPostID=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^ads/my_page/edit/([0-9]+)/dimg/([0-9]+)/{0,1}$  modules/boonex/ads/classifieds.php?action=my_page&mode=add&EditPostID=$1&dimg=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^ads/my_page/manage/{0,1}$  modules/boonex/ads/classifieds.php?action=my_page&mode=manage [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^ads/my_page/pending/{0,1}$  modules/boonex/ads/classifieds.php?action=my_page&mode=pending [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^ads/my_page/disapproved/{0,1}$  modules/boonex/ads/classifieds.php?action=my_page&mode=disapproved [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^ads/cat/([^/.]+)/{0,1}$  modules/boonex/ads/classifieds.php?catUri=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^ads/all/cat/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([^/.]+)/{0,1}$  modules/boonex/ads/classifieds.php?catUri=$3&page=$2&per_page=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^ads/subcat/([^/.]+)/{0,1}$  modules/boonex/ads/classifieds.php?scatUri=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^ads/all/subcat/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([^/.]+)/{0,1}$  modules/boonex/ads/classifieds.php?scatUri=$3&page=$2&per_page=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^ads/entry/([^/.]+)/{0,1}$  modules/boonex/ads/classifieds.php?entryUri=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^ads/tag/([^/.]+)/{0,1}$  modules/boonex/ads/classifieds_tags.php?tag=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^ads/calendar/{0,1}$  modules/boonex/ads/classifieds.php?action=show_calendar [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^ads/categories/{0,1}$  modules/boonex/ads/classifieds.php?action=show_categories [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^ads/tags/{0,1}$  modules/boonex/ads/classifieds.php?action=tags [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^ads/all_ads/{0,1}$  modules/boonex/ads/classifieds.php?action=show_all_ads [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^ads/top_ads/{0,1}$  modules/boonex/ads/classifieds.php?action=show_top_rated [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^ads/popular_ads/{0,1}$  modules/boonex/ads/classifieds.php?action=show_popular [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^ads/featured_ads/{0,1}$  modules/boonex/ads/classifieds.php?action=show_featured [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^search/tag/([^/.]+)/{0,1}$  search.php?Tags=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^browse/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)$ browse.php?sex=$1&age=$2&country=$3 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^m/(.*)$  modules/index.php?r=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^forum/groups/(.*)$  modules/boonex/forum/$1?orca_integration=groups [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^forum/events/(.*)$  modules/boonex/forum/$1?orca_integration=events [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^forum/store/(.*)$  modules/boonex/forum/$1?orca_integration=store [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^forum/$  modules/boonex/forum/index.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^forum/(.*)$  modules/boonex/forum/$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$  viewPage.php?ID=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .+ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ profile.php?ID=$1 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>

AddType application/vnd.adobe.air-application-installer-package+zip .air
AddType application/x-shockwave-flash .swf
```

When I go to the url "http://columbusnorthalumni.org/bricks/" it appears that I get redirected by the last rewrite rules even though the top rule should match and stop (due to the 'L' option).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the folder 'bricks' create a new .htaccess file. In that add the following:-

```
RewriteEngine off
```